# How do I use GitLab pajamas?

Tags: html, gitlab

Gitlab pajamas is a front-end framework that specifies all of the components (e.g. buttons) used by Gitlab: https://design.gitlab.com/

Does anyone know how I can use the Pajamas framework, as I would Bootstrap? I cannot find a setup guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't appear that you are meant to pajamas to write your own site (as you would something like bootstrap or prime-ng). As you say, they don't publish any information on how to get started, they publish nothing in their npm repository, and there is no publish step in their CI/CD pipeline. This is likely because the project is heavily insinuated to be a design/UX documentation repository as opposed to code for the components itself.

Instead, they do offer [GitLab UI](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ui) as a set of pre-built components that you can use within your projects. You can see a [gallery of what's available here](https://gitlab-org.gitlab.io/gitlab-ui/?path=/story/base-accordion--auto-collapse).